# Java - Linked List with Decisions

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I'm trying to find a data-structure to help me model this scenario...

I have a set of expressions that have two types:
1. Expressions that have a calculations that should be executed and return a true or false outcome
2. Expressions that print out information and have no return value
The expressions have a sequential order that depends on the outcome of their calculation.

The expressions are stored in the database and at runtime will be loaded into a data structure which will need to retain the order of the expressions and the decisions that should be followed depending on an expression's outcome.

Let me illustrate this with a simple example where there are 4 expressions and the first two are rules that when carried out have a true or false return value but the final 2 are just informational so after being executed the flow would continue to the next expression.

```
Expression 1: "5+5=10" If True then go to Expression 2 If False then go to Expression 4 
Expression 2: "6+1=7" If True then go to Expression 4 If False then go to Expression 3
Expression 3: "print hello" 
Expression 4: "print goodbye"
```

My immediate thought is that the data structure could be some sort of linked list that would need to have not only a next() method to point to the next expression but also true() and false() methods to point to the appropriate nodes in the case that the expression has a return value.

Is there any established way to model this type of relationship?

Comment: can you go from higher expression to lower espression? e.g. Expression 4: says go to Expression 2?

Answer (score 3):

You could simply use a Binary tree.

Comment: Possible but there are actually three possible decisions for each expression - true or false if there is a calculation but also a default next expression to go to in the event that there is no calculation.

Comment: @joechip You could use a B-Tree for multiple choice nodes.

Answer (score 0):

pseudo code:

```
LinkedList <Map <Integer><Decision>>
```

Where:

`Integer` - number of the decision

`Decision` - your function

And you could define `Logic` structure, for instance:

```
input  1 2 3 4 5 6
true   2 
false  4
```

it means if `1 ret true` then `ret 2` else ret `4`